# ThreadPool race-condition, closure, locking or something else?

Tags: c#, multithreading, closures, threadpool, manualresetevent

Still pretty new to threads so I'm sure it is one of those little gotchas and a repeat question, but I have been unable to find the answer browsing the threads.

I have a port scanner app in C#.
I'm using threadpools to spin up a new TcpClient for each port and probe if it's open.
After suffering through the concepts of closures and thread synchronization, I am having an issue where when multiple threads try to save their results to different indexes in the `Orchestrator.hosts` (List).

I have multiple threads trying to update a single List results object.  My understanding is this is fine as long as I lock the object on write, however I'm finding that on some updates, multiple entries are getting the same update.
IE, Thread #1 supposed to update `Hosts[0].Ports[0].Status` to "Open",
What happens:
Thread #1 updates multiple host with the port result despite passing a specific index for Hosts.
`Hosts[0].Ports[0].Status` to "Open",
`Hosts[1].Ports[0].Status` to "Open",
`Hosts[2].Ports[0].Status` to "Open",

Not sure where my problem is.  The Static method I'm calling to perform a probe of a given port

```
    public static void ScanTCPPorts()
    {
        // Create a list of portsToScan objects to send to thread workers
        //List<ScanPortRequest> portsToScan = new List<ScanPortRequest>();
    
        using (ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            int toProcess = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < hostCount; i++) // Starting at Begining
            {
                int currentHostId = i;
                // To hold our current hosts ID (Assign outside of threaded function to avoid race-condition)
                if (hosts[i].IsAlive || scanDefinition.isForced())
                {
                    int portCount = hosts[i].Ports.Count;
                    for (int p = 0; p < portCount; p++)
                    {
                        // Thread-safe Increment our workQueue counter
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref toProcess);
    
                        int currentPortPosition = p;
    
                        // We need to send the arrayIndex in to the thread function
                        PortScanRequestResponse portRequestResponse = new PortScanRequestResponse(hosts[currentHostId], currentHostId, hosts[currentHostId].Ports[currentPortPosition], currentPortPosition);
    
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                            new WaitCallback(threadedRequestResponseInstance => {
                                PortScanRequestResponse portToScan = threadedRequestResponseInstance as PortScanRequestResponse;
                                PortScanRequestResponse threadResult = PortScanner.scanTCPPort(portToScan);
                                // Lock so Thread-safe update to result
                                lock (Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex])
                                {
                                    if (threadResult.port.status == PortStatus.Open)
                                    {
                                        // Update result
Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex].Ports[portToScan.portResultIndex].status = PortStatus.Open;
                                        //Logger.Log(hosts[currentHostId].IPAddress + " " + hosts[currentHostId].Ports[currentPortPosition].type + " " + hosts[currentHostId].Ports[currentPortPosition].portNumber + " is open");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex].Ports[portToScan.portResultIndex].status = PortStatus.Closed;
                                    }
                                    // Check if this was the last scan for the given host
                                    if (Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex].PortScanComplete != true)
                                    {
                                        if (Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex].isCompleted())
                                        {
                                            Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex].PortScanComplete = true;
                                            // Logger.Log(hosts[currentHostId].IPAddress + " has completed a port scan");
                                            Orchestrator.hosts[portToScan.hostResultIndex].PrintPortSummery();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // Safely decrement the counter
                                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
                                    resetEvent.Set();
                            }), portRequestResponse);   // Pass in our Port to scan
                    }
                }
            }
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
```

Here is the worker process in a separate public static class.

```
    public static PortScanRequestResponse scanTCPPort(object portScanRequest) {
        PortScanRequestResponse portScanResponse = portScanRequest as PortScanRequestResponse;
        HostDefinition host = portScanResponse.host;
        ScanPort port = portScanResponse.port;
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient threadedClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    IAsyncResult result = threadedClient.BeginConnect(host.IPAddress, port.portNumber, null, null);
                    Boolean success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(Orchestrator.scanDefinition.GetPortTimeout(), false);
    
                    if (threadedClient.Client != null)
                    {
                        if (success)
                        {
                            threadedClient.EndConnect(result);
                            threadedClient.Close();
                            portScanResponse.port.status = PortStatus.Open;
                            return portScanResponse;
                        }
                    }
                } catch { }
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
        portScanResponse.port.status = PortStatus.Closed;
        return portScanResponse;
    }
```

Originally I was pulling the host index from a free variable, thinking this was the problem moved it to inside the delegate.
I tried locking the Hosts object everywhere there was a write.
I have tried different thread sync techniques (`CountdownEvent` and `ManualResetEvent`).

I think there is just some fundamental threading principal I have not been introduced to yet, or I have made a very simple logic mistake.

Comment: You may want to consider using `async` `await` with tasks, instead of using threads. This will increase performance and be much easier to write and understand.

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple threads trying to update a single List results object. My understanding is this is fine as long as I lock the object on write.

I haven't studied your code, but the above statement alone is incorrect. When a `List<T>`, or any other non-thread-safe object , is used in a multithreaded environment, all interactions with the object must be synchronized. Only one thread at a time should be allowed to interact with the object. Both writes and reads must be enclosed in `lock` statements, using the same locker object. Even reading the `Count` must be synchronized. Otherwise the usage is erroneous, and the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: lock was present in updates to the storage object.  As for sync on Count, I passed the count to the thread as a local-var through the delegate and avoided the free-variable model.

Answer (score 0):

I was hyper-focused on it being a thread issue because this was my firsts threaded project.  Turned out to be that I didn't realize copies of a List<> objects are references to their original object (reference type). I assumed my threads were accessing my save structure in an unpredictable way, but my arrays of ports were all referencing the same object.

This was a "reference type" vs "value type" issue on my List<> of ports.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).